# dml statistics null for LOAD DATA INTO query

Tags: google-bigquery

Going by this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-manipulation-language), DML only considers INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, maybe few more as well. Shouldn't LOAD DATA also be considered?

When querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS for LOAD_DATA query, dml_statistics comes as null although the query inserted some rows. As per expectation, it should return correct stats.

**UPDATE:**

For LOAD_DATA query, we still get this info from job_stage info.
but for LOAD & COPY jobs, both job_stage & dml_statistics are null.

Comment: BigQuery defines DML statements as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE.  While it is certainly true that LOAD DATA can be used to append new rows to a table, it is simply not considered a DML statement.